# How to grep word from file

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I want to grep some word inside a file from another file. My code is able to grep the word on last line of the file but not the word before it. I have no idea why and hope can get help here. Below is the perl script i using:

```
open(FILE1,"file1.txt") or die "Error, File1 could not open\n";           
open(FILE2,"file2.txt") or die "Error, File2 could not open\n";
open(FILE3, ">file3.txt") or die "Error, File3 could not open\n";

use strict; 
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my @file1=<FILE1>;
my @file2=<FILE2>;
my $j =0;
my $i =0;
my $zone =0;
for ($j=0; $j<=$#file2; $j++){
    $zone = $file2[$j];
    unless ( $zone =~ m/#(.*?)/ ) {
        print "$zone";
        my @fid = grep /$zone/ , @file1;
        @fid = uniq(@fid);
        s{^\s+|\s+$}{}g foreach @fid;                #cancel leading space
        for ($i=0; $i<=$#fid; $i++){
            print FILE3 "$fid[$i]\n";
        }
        #@fid=();

    }
}

close(FILE3);
```

My file1.txt is something like this:

```
i am a dog
i am a cat
we are the fish
he is a boy
she is a girl
```

My file2.txt is like this:

```
is
am
```

But my file3 can only show those sentence contain am but no is, if i put is in second line and am in first line then my file3 only contain the sentences with is. I not very sure why my code can only grep the last row in my file2. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

When reading from a file, the final newline is part of each line read. You can remove the newlines from the pattern array by [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp)ing:

```
chomp( my @file2 = <FILE2> );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can already do this with egrep :

```
egrep -f file2.txt file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The root of this problems is `chomp` - you're not removing linefeeds, so the matches aren't working.

But aside from that, there's a few problems with your code that could do with addressing:

- opening files, you should use 3 arg open with lexical file handles, as it's better style: `open (my $file1, '<', 'file1.txt' ) or die $!;`
- rather than a loop of loops, you'd probably be better off compiling up a 'match regex'.
- Instead of reading all of a file into an array, you can iterate line by line, and you don't need to use the memory.
- If you're iterating a loop, and *only* using the index to acccess the current element, you're far better off using `foreach my $line ( @things ) {` type syntax.

So your code actually could be reduced to something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $data, '<',"file1.txt") or die $!;
open(my $search, '<', "file2.txt") or die $!;
open(my $output, '>', "file3.txt" ) or die $!;

chomp ( my @search_terms = <$search> );

#quotemeta is needed to avoid 'special' regex characters doing things. 
my $search_regex = join "|", map { quotemeta }, @search_terms;

#note - '\b' denotes word boundary, which may not be what you want.  
#means 'is' won't match 'fish'
#so get rid of them if that's not what you want. 
$search_regex = qr/\b($search_regex)\b/;

print "Using: $search_regex\n";

select $output; #default print destination
while ( <$data> ) {
    print if m/$search_regex/;
}
```

Output (in 'file3.txt'):

```
i am a dog
i am a cat
he is a boy
she is a girl
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this .

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);


open(FILE1,"file1.txt") or die "Error, File1 could not open\n";           
open(FILE2,"file2.txt") or die "Error, File2 could not open\n"; 
open(FILE3, ">file3.txt") or die "Error, File3 could not open\n"; 

my @file1=<FILE1>;
my @file2=<FILE2>;
my $j =0;
my $i =0;

foreach my $main_line(@file1){
    chomp($main_line);
    foreach my $line(@file2){
        chomp($line);
        if ($main_line =~ /$line/i) {
            print FILE3 "$main_line\n";
        }
    }
}

close(FILE3);
```

thanks,
praveenzx~

Comment: Would benefit from a bit more explanation of what you've 'fixed' I think.